# How to inject a variable after each character in an echo statement for the entirety of a script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Please don't give me a direct solution, I'm trying to learn how to do this just for fun, could you guys point me in the right direction?

I want to create a little device or function I can apply to my scripts. If I have the following variables:

```
Vowel=; sleep 0.17
Consonant=; sleep 0.21
```

How would I set up a function or loop to achieve the following effect?

- For each character in the " " portion of each echo command in the script...
- Create a new "echo -n " " with the " " portion only storing the first character...
- Then after that, place the Vowel variable OR the Consonant Variable depending on if the character is a vowel or consonant...
- Do this until the last character in the echo command

The above function or script would take...

```
echo "Hello"
```

and turn it into...

```
echo -n "H" ; sleep 0.21 ; echo -n "e"  ; sleep 0.17 ; echo -n "l" ; sleep 0.21 ; echo -n "l" ; sleep 0.21 ; echo "o" ; sleep 0.17
```

The purpose of this would be to have any echo commands in the script be turned into the above to achieve the effect of the echo text appearing to be typed out on screen in the terminal.

Essentially I want to create a function that will eliminate having to type each echo command in my script in the long way above every time I want the echo command to appear as if its being typed out into the terminal

Thanks in advance!

---

#### EDIT

So after a bit of work, i came up with this

```
#!/bin/bash

Vowel= ; sleep 0.17
Consonant= ; sleep 0.21
array=()

#dummy function to test a string 
variable="hello"

function steve {

#start a 0, going up until i is greater than the number of characters in the variable 
for (( i=0; i<${#variable}; i++)); do

    #puts each charecter into an array 
    array+=($(echo "${variable:$i:1}"))

done


#for each item in the array which should be each letter in variable, echo on    the same line each letter, and sleep 
for i in "${array[@]}"

do


echo -n $i ; sleep 0.21



done 

#adds a space after the command 
echo ""

}

#calling the function as a dummy 
steve
```

The script so far seems to work, it spits out "hello" using the sleep

Now I'm stuck again, when i replace `;sleep 0.21` with `$Vowel`, it doesn't work
Why not?

Also, right now its only working off of the `$variable="hello"` string, how would i change this so that it can work off something like this

```
echo "hello" | steve
```

Comment: The best way to do this is with a function that you invoke like `echo "Hello" | typeit`. This function could have a `while read` loop to read each character, then echo it with the given delay.

Comment: so after each echo statement, i can do the pipe character to send that echo "hello" to a function (that i need to make) called "typeit"
I didn't know you could do that with the |  

Thanks!

Comment: Re: "Please don't give me a direct solution", whoops, read that too late.  Really, that'd be the single most important part of the question.  Please *lead* with that next time...

Answer (score 1):

some bash

```
# global vars for sleep intervals
Vowel=0.17
Consonant=0.21

# test if a character is a vowel
isvowel () { 
    local -l char=${1:-x};
    [[ "aeiou" == *"$char"* ]]
}

# do it
printslowly() {
    local text="$*"
    local char i
    for ((i=0; i < "${#text}"; i++)); do
        char=${text:i:1}
        if isvowel "$char"; then
            sleep $Vowel
        else
            sleep $Consonant
        fi
        printf "%s" "$char"
    done
    echo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need these:
(In case you want full gray field tips, they're on my desktop. `. . .` means you need to figure out this part yourself. )

1. **A map** which will keep the information if the character is a vowel or a consonant. You can use for this an associative array with letters as keys and as value either CONSONANT (C) or VOWEL (V).

   `declare . . . map` #declaration of an associative array map

   `map=( . . . . . . )` #fill it up with values
2. **Source reader** which you'll feed with input. This can be a function.

   `while read . . . . .; . . . . . . .; done < <(. . . . .)`
3. **Translator** turning what's taken into what's wanted.

   `${. . . . .}` #decode the value for character `c`. Remember there are lower and upper case characters. On top of this, inject what you like.
4. **Packaging** rounding it all up and making easily accessible to the outer world. You may just want it to be a sourcable function, or you might want it to be a script taking one word as an argument. You might also want it to be able to read standard input from pipes or interactively. Another functionality is reading files passed as arguments. Finally, you might want to give it writing powers, which would stuff new and old files with the output.

---

Reference:

- [Bash Associative Arrays](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-associative-arrays)
- [The read builtin command](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read)
- [The Linux Command Line, A Book By William Shotts](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php/)

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna have to do some reading on a lot of these terms, As you can probably see already, I'm not a programmer or skilled at coding. 

I'll do some research with this and come back to it with hopefully a better understanding of what I'm reading.

Comment: Yes, I agree that you miss some basic knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Function using `eval`, and `sed` code that turns letters and such into
various delays, plus some variables:

```
vowel=0.17 consonant=0.21
slowecho () 
{ 
    eval $(echo "$@" | \
    sed -n 's/./&\n/gp' | \
    sed -n '/[aeiouAEIOU]/{s/./echo -n "&"; sleep '"$vowel"';/p;b};
            /[[:alpha:]]/{ s/./echo -n "&"; sleep '"$consonant"';/p;b};
            /^$/{s/^$/echo;/p;b};
            /"/{s/"/echo -n "\\\x22"; sleep 0.1;/p;b};
            s/./echo -n "&"; sleep 0.1 ;/p')
}
```

Test:

```
time slowecho hello there
```

Output:

```
hello there

real    0m2.085s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.028s
```

The variables can be set on the fly, so this works too:

```
vowel=3 consonant=5
time slowecho hello
```

Output:

```
hello

real    0m21.030s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.020s
```

---

Notes: There's no need to set `vowel="; sleep 0.17", just the number is sufficient.  The`sed` code gets a bit ugly when dealing with '**"**' and '**\n**', which each need their own line.  Perhaps there's a better way...

For fun try `slowecho $(fortune)`.